# How do I get my QCombobox to refresh contents instead of drawing over themselves?

Tags: python, pyside, qcombobox

I have a series of pyside qcomboboxes.  The items are added dynamically.  The problem is that when items are added to the combobox, they draw over each other.  The QComboBox has an .update() method, but that doesn't correct the issue I'm having.  Hopefully this image will help clarify what is going on.

[image: img]

I've tried using the update() method, and I've looked around for this answer for days now to no avail.

I am using python, pyside and stylesheets for the background images.

Comment: I should also point out that they are not drawing over themselves while they are being dynamically added, only when you start scrolling the list do they draw over themselves.

Comment: You must provide an [MRE] if you want help, it also indicates the python and pyside versions you use.